# The magic number in GZip header is not correct EF migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget-package, entity-framework-migrations

I am using entity migration command like
PM> add-migration Test

After; I am getting error "The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."

ReInstall nuget package manager, reInstall vs2012, but not yet solve my problem?
How can I solve it.

```
PM> Add-Migration Test
System.IO.InvalidDataException: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.
   at System.IO.Compression.GZipDecoder.ReadHeader(InputBuffer input)
   ...
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.
```

Comment: yes, the db was damaged. I have reinstalled the mysql

Comment: Please post this as an answer if you have resolved your problem.

Comment: Not yet, I solved with another method.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after deleting the __MigrationHistory table.

Restoring an old backup of the database using Azure fixed it for me.

Comment: I managed to fix my issue by deleting every record from the _MigrationHistory table. I'm just worried this could cause further issues down the line with more migrations?